# Android - Loader for 1 record

Tags: android

Which is the best way to load the data for a single item (read only) detail activity?
Should i use LoaderManager or directly AsyncTask?

Comment: yes from sqlite. I have already a custom CursorLoader for getting the results

Comment: if you need a single record, you probably can read it directly, no need for loadermanager or asynctask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an Asyntask for best result:

```
Public class example extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
  {
        private ProgressDialog dialog;

        public example(Context context){
              dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog.setTitle("Demo");
            dialog.setMessage("Please Wait..");
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            return null;
        }

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
  }
```